# disable package installing programmatically

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, package

i developed a non-market application for a specific customer and they want me to disable package installing for the devices programmatically, because the users shoudn't do anything with their devices but using my app.
There are some applications in the market which are able to password protect the installing of packages, but i need to to it by myself, because my app needs to run updates or install addons without prompting for a password.
I build a receiver with the intent filter below:

```
<intent-filter>     
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL"/>
 </intent-filter>
```

but this will start after installing a package, not before.

I also tryed to receive a Broadcast while starting a package, in Order to capture the startup of `com.android.packageinstaller`, but neither i found a way to recive a package start, nor was I able to kill the package, if my application is not the starting process.
I tryed this:

```
ActivityManager servMng = (ActivityManager)context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

         List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> list =servMng.getRunningAppProcesses();
         if(list != null){
          for(int i=0;i<list.size();++i){
           if("com.android.packageinstaller".matches(list.get(i).processName)){
            int pid = android.os.Process.getUidForName("com.android.packageinstaller");
                  android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
           }else{

           }
          }
         }
```

How am I able to do that correctly?
The Devices are not Rooted, but the first installation of my app is done manually by myself, it will be no problem to confirm some security alerts for installing the feature.

Comment: You can't disable uninstall in Android. However, if you're clever and evil, you can make two apps, each of which installs the other when it is uninstalled.

Comment: I don't want to disable uninstalling but installing.

Comment: Sorry, right. That can't be done, either, and I can't even think of a clever, evil workaround.

Comment: I know that it could be done, e.g. the app "Applock" actualy do that. And btw, if you install this app, you have to type a passwort if you want to enter the settings. So you are not able to uninstall the app ^^

Comment: @2red13 Hi, Have you got any workaround for this?

Comment: I think this can be done only on rooted device. is this correct?

Comment: no, Applock also works on non rooted devices and unfortunally i haven't found any workaround yet.